# Is there a way to save a model using Tensorflow 2.6.0 so that it can be loaded back using Tensorflow 2.3.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I began writing my code with Tensorflow 2.6.0, but now I need to downgrade it to 2.3.0 since it needs to run on a GPU that doesn't support CUDA 11.

Some of the neural networks in my code are loaded from json files using the `keras.models.model_from_json` function, which apparently behaves differently in these two tf versions. While it works fine in 2.6.0, I get the following error in 2.3.0:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'
```

Since it is loaded correctly with the more recent version of tf, I'm trying to save it in another format to hopefully be able to load it with tf 2.3.0. I tried both the keras SavedModel and HDF5 approach as well as the tf.saved_model.load approach:

- When I try to load the models as SavedModels I get `OSError: Unable to open file Permission denied`, seems that keras is expecting a file rather than a folder;
- Using either the HDF5 method or the tf.saved_model module ends with `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` when trying to load the models.

And I'm stuck here. The aforementioned methods work without any issues when I load the models back using Tensorflow 2.6.0, so I'm sure I saved them correctly.

Any help from someone more knowledgeable than me would be appreciated.

Comment: You could consider converting it to [ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) or some other interop format.

Comment: Backward compatibility is a need, but forward compatibility is impossible :-)